# How to pass a php array as a post parameter in ajax call to a php file in the url

Tags: php, json

I want to pass a php array as a parameter to ajax call.I have done it with json_encode and JSON.parse . But I am ending up with a 
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input at JSON.parse ()

This is for an php application developed with XAMPP Server.

```
**myfile.php**
```

This is the file where I have a view link.On clicking that link , I need to pass the array data to the post file in the ajax, where I will display the content inside the modal.
For that I have used the json_encode() and JSON.parse() , but I am ending up with this error.

```
    <?php

$arrOne = array('test_arg_one' => 'Arg One','test_arg_two' => 'Arg Two','test_arg_three' => 'Arg Three');
$arrTwo = array('test_arg_one' => 'Arg One','test_arg_two' => 'Arg Two','test_arg_three' => 'Arg Three');
$arrThree = array('test_arg_one' => 'Arg One','test_arg_two' => 'Arg Two','test_arg_three' => 'Arg Three');

        $json_one = json_encode($arrOne);
        $json_two = json_encode($arrTwo);
        $json_three = json_encode($arrThree);

    ?>
    <html>
    <form >
     <a href="#" class="view_data" id="<?php echo $view['id'];?>">VIEW</a>
    </form>

    <div id="MyModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">

     <div class="modal-dialog"  style="    margin-top: -12%;">

      <!-- Modal Content: begins -->
      <div class="modal-content"  style="width: 950px; margin-left: -190px;">
        <div class="modal-header qutviewhead">
          <h4 class="modal-title" style="text-align: center; margin-right: 305px;">Test</h4>
          <!-- <button type="button" class="close qotviewclosebtn" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button> -->
        </div>

        <!-- Modal Body -->  
        <div class="modal-body meadqrypopmdbody"  style="height: 560px;  overflow: scroll; overflow-x: hidden;">

         <div class="header">
           <img src="img1.jpg" style="width: 100%;  height: 130px;">
         </div>
         <div style="display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap;">
           <div style="width: 15%;">
            <img src="img2.jpg" style="padding-top: 15px;  width: 105px;  height: 100%" align="left">
          </div>

          <div style="width: 85%;background: url('img3.jpg');  background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center; margin-top: 15px;">
            <div id="div_one">
              <div class="test-one">

              </div>

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div style="margin-top: 15px; text-align: center;">
          <p style="background: #2e3192; color: #fff; padding: 10px 10px;">Plot No.1148, West End Colony, Anna Nagar West Extension, Chennai-600 050. <br> 
            Ph : 044-26257357, 90421 33333. Email : abishek@senthilsafety.com, Web : www.ssspl.in
          </p>
        </div>


        <div class="header">
         <img src="img1.jpg" style="width: 100%;  height: 130px;">
       </div>
       <div style="display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap;">
         <div style="width: 15%;">
          <img src="img2.jpg" style="padding-top: 15px;  width: 105px;  height: 100%" align="left">
        </div>

        <div style="width: 85%;background: url('img3.jpg');  background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center; margin-top: 15px;">
          <div id="div_two">
            <div class="test-two">

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div style="margin-top: 15px; text-align: center;">
        <p style="background: #2e3192; color: #fff; padding: 10px 10px;">Plot No.1148, West End Colony, Anna Nagar West Extension, Chennai-600 050. <br> 
          Ph : 044-26257357, 90421 33333. Email : abishek@senthilsafety.com, Web : www.ssspl.in
        </p>
      </div>


      <div class="header">
       <img src="img1.jpg" style="width: 100%;  height: 130px;">
     </div>
     <div style="display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap;">
       <div style="width: 15%;">
        <img src="img2.jpg" style="padding-top: 15px;  width: 105px;  height: 100%" align="left">
      </div>

      <div style="width: 85%;background: url('img3.jpg');  background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center; margin-top: 15px;">
        <div id="div_three">
          <div class="test-three">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div style="margin-top: 15px; text-align: center;">

    </div>  


    </div>
    <div class="cusfooter">

      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default modcanbtn" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>



    </div>

    </div>
    </div>
    </div>



    </html>


    $('.view_data').click(function(){
      var record = $(this).attr("id");


        var obj = JSON.parse('<?= $json_one; ?>');
        var facArg1 = obj.arg1;
        var facArg2 = obj.arg2;
        var facArg3 = obj.arg3;


        var obj1 = JSON.parse('<?= $json_two; ?>');
        var facArg11 = obj1.arg1;
        var facArg21 = obj1.arg2;
        var facArg31 = obj1.arg3;


        var obj2 = JSON.parse('<?= $json_three; ?>');
        var facArg12 = obj2.arg1;
        var facArg22 = obj2.arg2;
        var facArg32 = obj2.arg3;


        $.ajax({
          url:"testCat.php",
          method:"post",
          data:{'id':record,'facArg1':facArg1,'facArg2':facArg2,'facArg3':facArg3,'facArg11':facArg11,'facArg21':facArg21,'facArg31':facArg31,'facArg12':facArg12,'facArg22':facArg22,'facArg32':facArg32},
          success:function(data){
            var divs = data.split('------');

            $(".test-one").html(divs[0]); 
            $(".test-two").html(divs[1]); 
            $(".test-three").html(divs[2]); 

            $("#MyModal").modal("show");

          } 
        });

    })



**testCat.php** [file in the ajax call]
```

This the content getting displayed inside the modal.

```
    if(isset($_POST['cert_id']))
    {


    $output_one = '<style>
    .borderNone table,td,th{
      border:none!important;
      text-align:left !important;
      padding:0px !important;
    }
    </style>
    <div style="text-align:center;">
    <section>
    <table align="right">
    <tr>
    <th style="text-align: right;">Date: 20/09/2019</th>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </section>
    <section>
    <div style="padding-top:35px;"></div>
    <p><b><u>TEST FORM</u></b></p>
    <p><b>SEC</b></p>
    </section>

    <br>
    <section>
    <table style="border:none;">';
    $arrValues = array();
    if(isset($_POST['facArg1']) && ($_POST['facArg1'] != '')){
      $arrValues['arg_one'] = $_POST['facArg1'];
    }
    if(isset($_POST['facArg2']) && ($_POST['facArg2'] != '')){
       $arrValues['arg_two'] = $_POST['facArg2'];
    }
    if(isset($_POST['facArg3']) && ($_POST['facArg3'] != '')){
       $arrValues['arg_three'] = $_POST['facArg3'];
    }

    $i = 1;
    foreach($arrValues as $key => $val){
      $output_one .='<tr>
      <td>'.$i.'.'.$key.'</td>
      <td>'.$val.'</td>
      </tr>';
      $i++;
    }

    $i = count($arrValues) + 1;
    foreach($pdfOne as $key => $val){
    $output_one .= '<tr>
    <td>'.$i.'.'.$key.'</td>
    <td style="padding: 0px 0px 0px 40px !important;">'.$val.'</td>
    </tr>';

    $i++;             
    }

    $output_one .= '</table>
    </section></div>
    <br>';

    $output_two = '
    <div style="text-align:center;"><section>
    <table align="right">
    <tr>
    <th style="text-align: right;">Date: 20/09/2019</th>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </section>
    <section>
    <div style="padding-top:35px;"></div>
    <p><b><u>TEST 2</u></b></p>
    </section>

    <br>
    <section>
    <table style="border:none;">';
    $arrValuesOne = array();
    if(isset($_POST['facArg11']) && ($_POST['facArg11'] != '')){
      $arrValuesOne['arg_one'] = $_POST['facArg11'];
    }
    if(isset($_POST['facVillage21']) && ($_POST['facVillage21'] != '')){
      $arrValuesOne['arg_two'] = $_POST['facArg21'];
    }
    if(isset($_POST['facAdd31']) && ($_POST['facAdd31'] != '')){
      $arrValuesOne['arg_three'] = $_POST['facArg31'];
    }

    $i = 1;
    foreach($arrValuesOne as $key => $val){
      $output_two .='<tr>
      <td>'.$i.'.'.$key.'</td>
      <td>'.$val.'</td>
      </tr>';
      $i++;
    }

    $i = count($arrValuesOne) + 1;

    foreach($pdfTwo as $key => $val){
    $output_two .= '<tr>
    <td>'.$i.'.'.$key.'</td>
    <td style="padding: 0px 0px 0px 40px !important;">'.$val.'</td>
    </tr>';

    $i++;             
    }

    $output_two .= '</table>
    </section></div>
    <br>';


    $output_three = '<style>
    .borderNone table,td,th{
      border:none!important;
      text-align:left !important;
      padding:0px !important;
    }
    </style>
    <div style="text-align:center;"><section>
    <table align="right">
    <tr>
    <th style="text-align: right;">Date:20/09/2019</th>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </section>
    <section>
    <div style="padding-top:35px;"></div>
    <p><b><u>TET</u></b></p>
    </section>

    <br>
    <section>
    <table style="border:none;">';
    $arrValuesTwo = array();
    if(isset($_POST['facName12']) && ($_POST['facName12'] != '')){
      $arrValuesTwo['arg_one'] = $_POST['facName12'];
    }
    if(isset($_POST['facVillage22']) && ($_POST['facVillage22'] != '')){
      $arrValuesTwo['arg_two'] = $_POST['facVillage22'];
    }
    if(isset($_POST['facAdd32']) && ($_POST['facAdd32'] != '')){
     $arrValuesTwo['arg_three'] = $_POST['facAdd32'];
    }

    $i = 1;
    foreach($arrValuesTwo as $key => $val){
      $output_three .='<tr>
      <td>'.$i.'.'.$key.'</td>
      <td>'.$val.'</td>
      </tr>';
      $i++;
    }

    $i = count($arrValuesTwo) + 1;
    foreach($pdfThree as $key => $val){
    $output_three .= '<tr>
    <td>'.$i.'.'.$key.'</td>
    <td style="padding: 0px 0px 0px 40px !important;">'.$val.'</td>
    </tr>';

    $i++;             
    }

    $output_three .= '</table>
    </section></div>
    <br>';


    $output_two = '<div class="break-before"></div>'.$output_two; 
    $output_three = '<div class="break-before"></div>'.$output_three;
    echo $output_one.'------'.$output_two.'------'.$output_three;


    }

Kindly help me to solve this error.
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (myfile.php:1093)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.dispatch (jquery.3.2.1.min.js:3)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.q.handle (jquery.3.2.1.min.js:3)

I want the array values to get displayed inside the modal.
```

Comment: can you paste the page source to see your resulting js code. as your error implies it must be an "Unexpected end of JSON input"